# At what time is the pizza supposed to be/get delivered? How would a native speaker say that?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm wondering mostly in the informal context of a chat room. Basically:

> Person A: I just ordered a pizza!
>
> Me: At what time is it getting delivered?
>
> Me: At what time is it getting here?
>
> Me: When would it get here?
>
> Me: How soon is it getting delivered?

Mostly is that I don't want to sound like the non-native speaker who ends up writing a super long sentence for something that could have been said in a much simpler way.

Comment: When will the pizza be here? How long will it take to get here? When is the pizza supposed to be here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a fairly formal, clear way of asking the question.  In normal conversation with friends or in a chat room, you would probably want to be substantially more informal.  There are a bunch of ways of saying this, but off the top of my head, I would say something like:

> When is the pizza coming?
>   When is the pizza supposed to get here/there?
>   How long until the pizza gets here/there?

There is an unspoken "will it be" after the word "long" in the third version.

Answer (score 1):

Those are all fine sentences. However, I suggest "What time …" instead of "At what time …".

Comment: You suggest removing the "At" just because of the informal context?

Comment: I would drop "at" in any context. "What time" is sufficient.

Comment: Just read this article and seems like you're right: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/correct-grammar-usage-of-at.html (because "at" is a preposition and should connect something)

Comment: I wouldn't consider "At what time…" to be wrong; it's just better without the "at".